# Cosa signfica "sta sul discrime"?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-meaning, meaning, vocabulary

Cosa significa la frase "sta sul discrime"? Non si trova la parola "discrime" nel dizionario...

Comment: La stanchezza mi ha fatto leggere _discrimine_, ma forse è lo stesso errore che ha fatto in senso inverso chi ha scritto la frase. A proposito: qual è il soggetto della frase?

Comment: e' possibile che sia un problema di correzione o di proofing. qui c'e' la frase: "si e' detto che Rodari sta sul discrime in cui essa non si distingue dall'altra", quindi una persona...

Comment: forse un po come "soglia" o "confine"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sarà un refuso (o una forma obsoleta?) per *[discrimine](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/discrimine/)*.

Comment: Google engram viewer [mostra dei picchi](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=discrime&year_start=1500&year_end=2000&corpus=22&smoothing=0&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cdiscrime%3B%2Cc0) un paio di secoli fa. Mah?

Comment: @WalterTross: Giusto. In certi casi è semplicemente un problema di scansione (come «cessilalcs discrime*. cule militares,»), ma si direbbe che in rari casi si usasse proprio così («Ora più che mai m' accorgo, che picciolissimo errore nel principio cansa massima differenza e discrime d' errore in fine», dove però “cansa” dovrebbe essere “causa”). In ogni caso, se il testo dell'OP parlava di Gianni Rodari è un testo moderno, e sono incline a pensare che sia un refuso.

Comment: potrebbe essere uso letterario oppure sembra improbabile? Il testo che sto leggendo inserisce molta sintassi "avant", metatesi / parole inventate e cose del genere